# How to email worksheet to yourself in Excel/VBA (change the email dynamically depending on outlook account open)

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Right now I have a workbook with some VBA that will email one user (email address is hard coded) when a button is pressed. It works great. However, I was wondering if it were possible to "cc" the email to the the user who is pressing the button to email. It could be from 10-15 different people.

Right now the below code will email "orders@myemail.com" a copy of the sheet called "Print", and in the inbox it comes from the correct user. Somehow it is able to tap into the users email and send it automatically for them, so I'm thinking there must be a way for them to CC themselves too.

All email accounts will be on Microsoft Oulook.

Here is the code that emails one person (I got it from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail2.htm):

```
  'Sub that emails the 3rd sheet in the body of an email
    Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()
    Call UnProtect
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

    'RangetoHTML function is copied in the module after this sub.

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        Set rng = Nothing

        Set rng = Sheets("Print").UsedRange

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

            With OutMail
                .To = "orders@myemail.com" 
                .CC = ""                              
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "New Order from Employee"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)   
                .Send   'or use .Display
             End With 
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Call Protect
    End Sub
```

So to reiterate what I'm asking, is there anyway that when user1@email.com sends in an order/sends an email, that it "cc"s it to himself, and when user2@email.com does the same thing it only cc's himself. Dynamically changes based on who's account has the workbook open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with application.Session.CurrentUser.Address to get email id

```
Sub EmailWithCCTome()
Dim outlookobj As Object
Dim emailitem As Object
Set outlookobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailitem = outlookobj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With emailitem
.To = toemail
.CC = outlookobj.Session.CurrentUser.Address
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to program some way to capture the email address you want to cc somewhere on your sheet / form  and store it as a string variable (or pass the .Value reference directly to the .CC field) and / or use the sheet reference.  Something like:

```
   Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()
    Call UnProtect
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

    'RangetoHTML function is copied in the module after this sub.

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        **Dim ccEmail As String**

{your code here}

       ccEmail = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value ' or where ever you capture the email

{more of your code here}

            With OutMail
                .To = "orders@myemail.com" 
                **.CC = ccEmail**
{rest of your code}
```

There's no reliable way for Excel / VBA to know an email address without you capturing it.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I press the button and the VBA runs and sends an email...it has it in my "sent items" as sent by me. It uses the active outlook account. All I want is it to also send it TO me.

Comment: There are options in Outlook to automatically send you an email, I thought you were looking for a excel / VBA solution.

Comment: Right but I don't want to go around to 10-15 peoples outlooks account and change settings, especially cuz there is a possibility that these people could be changing every few months. I was indeed looking for an excel/vba solution to copy itself on the email.

Comment: My advice would be to put some input on your worksheet or form to capture the email address and pass it as a variable to the routine.